# When I search the help system, I never get any response

Tags: macos, imac, search

My iMac is generally fast, but when I search the help system, I never get any response.

The help system works fine if I simply navigate it, but search never returns anything.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would download the demo of TinkerTool System and run the “Repair Help Viewer” routine.

http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerToolSys4.html

**Menu ▹ User** – then the **Repair** panel – then **Repair “Help Viewer”**

See the online documentation:

http://www.bresink.com/osx/300644207/Docs-en/pgs/0220-User.html

Search for the literal text:

Repair “Help Viewer”

-ccs

Comment: Tool System 4 was a collection of system utility features helping you in performing advanced administration tasks on Apple Macintosh computers running OS X Yosemite or OS X El Capitan.

These historic operating systems can no longer support the current safety standards for Internet communication. Apple does not provide the necessary security certificates and TLS versions, so these systems cannot contact our license servers any longer. For this reason, distribution of the program had to be stopped. Customer support for this product ended on October 1, 2021.